# Data sharing in ember

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to understand how to share data between my controllers/routes.

I have an application that's displaying data about companies. Here are the routes I want:

```
 /                summary info
 /companies       list of all companies with some more detail
 /companies/:id   details about a single company
```

Now, the data required for all three routes is contained in a single array of company data. So, I want that data to load when the app starts up, and then be used for each route. There are also additional methods I will need on the controller that should be shared.

It is clear that the second and third routes are nested, so I can share the data from the `CompaniesController` when I link to a specific company, by passing in that company's data:

```
{{#linkTo 'company' company}}{{ company.name }}{{/linkTo}}
```

But the summary route is where I'm getting stuck. The two options I've come up with:

1. Create the `CompaniesController` with any additional methods I need, and create the `IndexController` by extending it

   ```
   App.IndexController = App.CompaniesController.extend({});
   ```

   Then, as far as I can tell, both routes will need to find the models:

   ```
   App.Router.map(function() {
       this.resource('companies');
   });

   App.CompaniesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
       model: function() {
           return App.Company.find();
       }
   });

   App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
       model: function() {
           return App.Company.find();
       }
   });
   ```

   Seems like there should be a better way, since I'll have to repeat this for each new route I add (e.g. `/revenue`).
2. Nest the `summary` route within the `companies` resource, and give it a path of '/'. What I don't like about this is that the 'nesting' of my UI doesn't match the data. It also seems like I'll have to redefine the `model` property for each route.

Is there another option that's better?

**tl;dr: How should I share data across controllers?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To share data beetwen controllers the correct way would be to use the [`needs` API](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/).

Assuming your `CompaniesController` has all the data that you want to make available to other controllers you should define it via `needs`, this can be a simple string, or an array of strings if you define more then one.

```
App.MyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['companies'],
  myFunction: function() {
    // now you can access your companies controller like this
    this.get('controllers.companies');
  }
});
```

To make things more easy accessible you could additionally define a binding, for example:

```
App.MyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['companies'],
  companiesBinding: 'controllers.companies',
  myFunction: function() {
    // now you can access your companies controller like this
    this.get('companies');
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Coming from backbone I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this. It seems like controllers can be used for data sharing only; in backbone, I'd have a `companies` collection which multiple views could access. In short, is it appropriate in ember to create a controller solely for the purpose of storing + sharing arrays of models?

Comment: If you have data like 'application settings', than having a SettingsController which is not part of a route/controller/view combo is fine. You can then use the needs API to make your settings available to other controllers. But if your data is related to the resources tree you have defined then a particular controller for each resource is the better approach, you can still share all types of controllers tough.

Comment: Sorry to butt in here, I want to clarify something. @intuitivepixel Does this work in the opposite direction? Index route `needs` Companies? Does this `needs` do a lookup on the Container or do the route hooks fire too?

Comment: @DarshanSawardekar, be my guest :) what do you mean with the opposite direction? In terms of binding?

Comment: Say `IndexController` corresponding to the above `/` summary route, uses `needs` `companies`. Now it has a controller reference but where is the `CompaniesController` getting data from? Do the CompaniesRoute hooks/setupController fire?

Comment: @DarshanSawardekar, or do you mean if a route will be looked up by having a independent controller which has no route?

Comment: @DarshanSawardekar, well, I guess you have different options to set the content on the `CompaniesController` other then the model hook nor the setupController, by requiring it in the IndexRoute and set the content of the `CompaniesController` there, makes sense?

Comment: @intuitivepixel How to set the content of the `CompaniesControllers` from the `IndexController`? I implemented this, and indeed it only works if I first visit the `companies` route then go back to the `index` route.

Comment: I see, so `IndexRoute` sideloads `Companies`, setupController uses `controllerFor` and sets the models on it then any  `needs` bindings have the data since it's sideloaded. Makes sense. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @DarshanSawardekar, can you read minds :P or do you have access to the NSA systems :) that was exactly what i wanted to say :) you are welcome

Comment: Would you mind explaining the details? I've asked a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749865/how-can-i-initialize-a-controller-from-another-controller-that-needs-it