# How can I initialize a controller from another controller that 'needs' it?

Tags: ember.js

Say I have two controllers, a `CompaniesController` and an `IndexController`. It turns out that all the data my `Index` route needs comes from the `CompaniesController`. So, I've specified my `IndexController` like this:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: 'companies',
});
```

This works well if the `CompaniesController` is already initialized, but what about the first time I visit the site? `CompaniesController` is empty.

So, I need to initialize the data for `CompaniesController` from within the `IndexController`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `setupController` and `controllerFor` within the `IndexRoute`:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('company');
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('companies').set('model', model);
  }
});
```

Comment: I was about to answer, sorry for the delay... but I see It was better to wait, now you have figured it out by yourself, which gives more self estimation :)

Comment: You will want to move/group the `App.Company.find` into the `model` or `afterModel` hook, so that it will pause for the data to load. Or chain it to another promise if you are already loading data in these hooks.

Comment: @DarshanSawardekar But isn't the `model` hook used to set the model on the current route? I wouldn't to set the array of companies as the model for the `IndexController`, right?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you may want to reverse the dependency and have your CompaniesController depend on Application, like so:

```
App.CompaniesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: 'application',
    contentBinding: 'controllers.application.companies'
});
```

Then, just initialize your application as needed when it first loads the base route.